# how to set $MYVIMRC?

Tags: vim

I read lot posts, lso few here on SO but nohing usefull, what I want to do simply is to set $M to open vimrc while running vim (coding) so simply when I type `:edit $M`  vimrc file is open and I can edit it and as I understand it correctly when I type `:source $M` vim writes changes and it returns to the actual file I was editing (coding). I run on linux fullpath to vimrc is : `/etc/vimrc`

Comment: This question seems to be about a text editor, not a programming problem.

Comment: @TZHX I think this question belongs here, [as discussed in the meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-do-they-belong-to-stack-overflow-or-super-user)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like the (better) answer above, here's the answer to your actual question...

Vim uses environment variables freely and happily.  If you run vim like this:

```
$ M=~/.vimrc vim
```

then you will be able to do the

```
:e $M
:source $M
```

that you were wanting to do.

If you do this either on the command line (for this session) or in your .bashrc:

```
export M=~/.vimrc
```

then that environment variable will be available when you run vim in other ways as well.

Incidentally, I'm not familiar with your expectation of how `:source` will work. I would expect that you would have to `:w` to save, then run your `:source $M` and then do `:e #` to get back to your previous file you were editing.  Easier would be to open a new window or tab, probably, but all that is personal preference.

Comment: It is not necessary to set the environment variable on the command line or on the .bashrc -- it can be set directly on Vim or .vimrc: `let $M=~/.vimrc`. Actually it would be better to replace $M with $MYVIMRC or set it like this: `let $M=$MYVIMRC`, as Vim automagically sets $MYVIMRC to `~/.vimrc`, `~/_vimrc`, `~/.vim/vimrc`, `~/vimfiles/vimrc` or any other location it finds your configuration file.

Comment: I set it like you write but it has some strnage problem with that    `let $MYVIMRC=/etc/vimrc
let $M=$MYVIMRC
`     but when I do   `:e $M  ` vim opens new file  called "$M"

Answer (score 1):

From http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/07.html

```
:nnoremap <leader>ev :vsplit $MYVIMRC<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>sv :source $MYVIMRC<cr>
```

Then (assuming `-` is your leader) you can just type

```
-ev
```

to edit your .vimrc and just type

```
-sv
```

to source it.

(Obviously those mapping lines need to be put in your .vimrc themselves so that they are available moving forward.)

That's not quite the answer to your question, but hopefully even more direct that what you were hoping for...

(Check out http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/06.html to see how to define  if you haven't done that before.)

Comment: so i add these mappings to vimrc    `let $MYVIMRC=/etc/vimrc
let $M=$MYVIMRC
nnoremap <leader>ev :vsplit $MYVIMRC<cr>
nnoremap <leader>sv :source $MYVIMRC<cr>
`     but it is not working - I do :e $M, :e $MYVIMRC and vim states error on the in teh vimrc file everytime i run it. also try -ev but since it states error on $MYVIMRC OR $M so the mapping does nothing and also how do I find out what is my leader

Answer (score 0):

so I find out how to set leader `let mapleader = ","

nmap <leader>v :tabedit $MYVIMRC<CR>`
    http://vimcasts.org/episodes/updating-your-vimrc-file-on-the-fly/
but problem is wtih `let $MYVIMRC=/etc/vimrc`    what could be wrong on that?? I have my vimrc just there in /etc

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Peter's answers, you might simply create a link:

`$ ln -s /etc/vimrc ~/.vimrc`

Comment: Can you please check what's the output of this command: `:echo $MYVIMRC`?

Comment: hm, so it probably means that you somehow cleared your $MYVIMRC variable. Please remove from your vimrc file this line, where you set the variable (probably `let $MYVIMRC=/etc/vimrc`) and check again. When you start vim, this variable should be set, by checking one by one locations in specific order (see `:h vimrc` for that order). $MYVIMRC is not set when you specify alternative config file with `vim -u /path/to/alternative/vimrc`.